# MySql deleting rows after a given time. Error 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1537019628' on a timestamp

Tags: mysql

I need to delete rows in the table alerts that are older than a given date. I have a date_created column that is an automatic time stamp set as a default value. I run a query from my windows form when it loads to execute this code:

```
delete from shopmanager.alerts 
where date_created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))
```

It does not work in the foirm so I tried it in Workbench and got the message:

> 0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1537019628' for column 'date_created' at row 1

date_created is set as TIMESTAMP and the default value is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
Why is it returning this error on a date it created itself? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `date_created` is `TIMESTAMP` then you should not be using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` for the comparison. The output of `DATE_SUB()` should be in the correct format.

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` type is a `DATETIME` type, not an int like a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Michael Berkowski's comment, this is the code modification that worked perfectly for anyone else having this issue:

```
delete from shopmanager.alerts where date_created < (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

If is a timestamp you only need to use this:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY
```